# Replace Old Password with a New

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a script that consists of following. When I run I get the error saying "sed: no input files".
I am trying to read old password from the database(which I already have the script) and trying to replace it with a new password.Everything before it works fine, I get error due to this part.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
old_passwd=${line%,*}
new_passwd=${line#*,}
echo $old_passwd
echo $new_passwd
done < RESULT.txt


for server in `head SERVERS.txt`; do
echo $server:
ssh username@$server grep -rl "$old_passwd" /usr/logs/test1 | xargs sed -i -e "s/$old_passwd/$new_passwd/g" /usr/logs/test1
done
```

Comment: Note that single quoting the sed expression keeps `$old_passwd`  and `$new_passwd` from being expanded.

Comment: Thanks. Now after adding the file name that error is gone, but it now says "grep: /usr/logs/test1: No such file or directory" . I have made sure the file exist with appropriate permissions.

Comment: The file exists on the remote server or the local server? This script will run `grep` on the remote server but change the matching files on the local machine (the `| xargs ...` part of the command executes locally).

Comment: That's not an answer to the question exactly but ok. That `grep` error seems to indicate that it isn't present on at least one remote server.

Comment: @EtanReisner The RESULT.txt exists in local server only and text1 file exists in remote server only. The grep and | xargs... should run on the remote server. We are trying to change database password of multiple remote servers from one local server

Comment: To get the `xargs` to run on the remote server you need to quote the entire command to `ssh` (or possibly just escape the `|` so your local shell doesn't see it.)

Comment: @ryekayo did that the error continues.

Comment: Try the suggestion of @Etan or start testing with `ssh username@$server grep -rl "$old_passwd" /usr/logs/test1 | xargs echo "$(hostname)"`

Comment: @ryekayo `xargs` puts its inputs on the command line. So putting the file on the command is, at best, redundant and at worst incorrect.